# Как можно сделать объедение union с union и как упростить обращение к элементам

Tags: c

Мне нужно как-то объединить два union, а именно объединить 'unionDio' с '_DIO_MIN':

```
    typedef union {
    uint16_t ADC[6];
    struct {
     uint16_t det_24V;
     uint16_t detCurrent_24V;
     uint16_t det_5V;
     uint16_t detCurrent_5V;
     uint16_t detReserve;
     uint16_t reserve;
    };
} unionAdc;

typedef union {
    uint16_t DIO[32];
    struct {
     uint16_t RTC_Year;
     uint16_t RTC_Mon;
     uint16_t RTC_Day;
     uint16_t RTC_Hour;
     uint16_t RTC_Min;
     uint16_t RTC_Sec;
     float    SysTimer;
     float    WRK_Hour;
     uint16_t ASU_P_Mode;
     uint16_t ASU_P_Speed;
     uint16_t ASU_P_Adr;
     unionAdc ADC;
    };
} unionDio;


typedef union{
    uint16_t word;
    struct{
        uint8_t Lo;
        uint8_t Ho;
    };
} _DIO_MIN[32];


typedef union{
    uint16_t word;
    struct{
        uint8_t Ho;
        uint8_t Lo;
    };
} _DIO_MID[128];


typedef union{
    uint16_t word;
    struct{
        uint8_t Ho;
        uint8_t Lo;
    };
} _DIO_MAX[4096];

typedef struct DIO{
       unionDio DIO00;
       _DIO_MIN DIO_MIN[63];      
       _DIO_MID DIO_MID[32];      
       _DIO_MAX DIO_MAX[4];      
       float    GLOB[8192];
       uint16_t ASUIO[32768];
       uint8_t  LOCALL[32768];
       float    STATDATA[32768];
       char     ERRORS[80];
       int      READYINPUT;
       char     DISP1[2][30][95];
       char     DISP2[2][30][95];
       char     DISP3[2][30][95];
       char     DISP4[2][30][95];
} _SysMem;
```

Comment: что значит «объединить?» засунуть их в одну структуру?

Comment: да. Хочу засунуть unionDio в  _DIO_MIN

Comment: всё равно не понимаю, что ты хочешь сделать... `struct foo {unionDio d; _DIO_MIN min};` тебя устроит?

Comment: Не совсем. Я хочу чтобы было вот так 'SysMem.DIO_MIN[0][0].RTC_Year' и вот 'SYSMEM.DIO_MIN[1][0].Ho'. Я не знаю как сделать  'SysMem.DIO_MIN[0][0].RTC_Year'